# What is a method to prove this trigonometric recursion without mathematical induction?

Tags: alternative-proof, recursion, trigonometric-series

tl:dr at the end:

So I started of scribbling this simple function in my notebook

$ f(\theta) = (1+\sin\theta + \cos\theta)$

$ =  \sin^2\theta + \cos^2\theta + \sin\theta + \cos\theta$

$ = (\sin\theta + \cos\theta)^2 + \sin\theta +\cos\theta  - \sin2\theta$

$ = (\sin\theta + \cos\theta)*(1 + \sin\theta + \cos\theta) - \sin2\theta$

Doing this once again on the $1 + \sin\theta + \cos\theta $

$ = (\sin\theta + \cos\theta)*((\sin\theta + \cos\theta)^2 + (\sin\theta + \cos\theta)- \sin2\theta)) - \sin2\theta$

$ = (\sin\theta + \cos\theta)^2*(1 + \sin\theta + \cos\theta) - \sin2\theta(1+ \sin\theta + \cos\theta)$

after $n$ such steps:

$f(\theta) = (\sin\theta + \cos\theta)^n(1+\sin\theta + \cos\theta) - \sin2\theta*\Sigma_{k=0}^{k=n-1}(\sin\theta + \cos\theta)^k = 1 + \sin\theta + \cos\theta$

My question is how do I prove this identity true $\forall \space n \space \epsilon \space W$

$1 + \sin\theta + \cos\theta = (\sin\theta + \cos\theta)^n(1+\sin\theta + \cos\theta) - \sin2\theta*\Sigma_{k=0}^{k=n-1}(\sin\theta + \cos\theta)^k $

tl:dr

In a non inductive manner. I find it quite intriguing that the right hand side is independent of $n$ and I want to prove it without knowing it's true.
Thank you.

Comment: By reverse engineering I assume you mean mathematical induction (the way that you derived it)?

Comment: The sum is Geometric. It has value $(1-a^n)/(1-a)$, where $a=\sin\theta+\cos\theta$. A bit of arithmetic shows the result.

Comment: Edit: This was fairly easy.. I had made mistakes earlier with the algebra.
I got it :) thanks @DavidMitra

Comment: You're welcome. I should have mentioned the case $\sin\theta+\cos\theta=1$ needs a different argument.